# Word for someone who makes decisions based purely on business or what would be most efficient?

Tags: american-english, business-language

A decision made regardless of ethical consequences.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, Madski. Could you clarify exactly what the question is? Is the title the question?

Comment: Madski, how should your terms be defined? Word for someone who makes decisions based purely on business *might* match what would be most efficient and where is that written? A decision made regardless of ethical consequences *might* be more businesslike, or more efficient or both but can you justify either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word [***pragmatic***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pragmatic) (M/W) has that meaning, although it is more often used in the sense of merely practical, rather than amoral.